# adapter contains an image and text to be add directly to the spinner

Tags: android

Can you help me with this question please?

Is there an adapter that contains an image and some text that can be added directly to the spinner?

Another requirement is that the image selected from an external file isn't in a drawable file

Answer (score 0):

take look on this , and in your custom adapter getView method select your source you need for your imageview

http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286